# wcf data services 5.1.0 rc

Tags: wcf-data-services

I am getting this error on Chrome v19.

I am doing a batch request to the WCF Data Service 5.1 rc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/.../metadata">
 <code></code>
 <message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
 <innererror>
   <message>A supported MIME type could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None of the supported type(s) 'multipart/mixed' matches the content type 'application/xml'.</message>
   <type>Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataContentTypeException</type>
   <stacktrace>
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.MediaTypeUtils.GetFormatFromContentType(String contentTypeName, ODataPayloadKind[] supportedPayloadKinds, MediaTypeResolver mediaTypeResolver, MediaType& mediaType, Encoding& encoding, ODataPayloadKind& selectedPayloadKind)&#xD;
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.MediaTypeUtils.GetFormatFromContentType(String contentTypeHeader, ODataPayloadKind[] supportedPayloadKinds, MediaTypeResolver mediaTypeResolver, MediaType& mediaType, Encoding& encoding, ODataPayloadKind& selectedPayloadKind, String& batchBoundary)&#xD;
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.ProcessContentType(ODataPayloadKind[] payloadKinds)&#xD;
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.ReadFromInput[T](Func`2 readFunc, ODataPayloadKind[] payloadKinds)&#xD;
     at Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataMessageReader.CreateODataBatchReader()&#xD;
     at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleBatchRequest()
   </stacktrace>
 </innererror>
</error>
```

Comment: What's the content type you are sending from the client?

Comment: contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose", type: "PUT",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: qry,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("MaxDataServiceVersion", "3.0");
                    },

Comment: And what is the URL you send it to? Maybe grab a request/response trace with Fiddler.

Comment: yes it's showing result in fiddler but not showing in my browser, i am using autocomplete jquery control to get data from wcf data service that i have updated in 5.1.0 -rc and V3 protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The content type of the batch request needs to be 'multipart/mixed' and follow this format:

[OData.org batch request specification](http://www.odata.org/documentation/batch)

Individual requests in the batch request can have json formatting, but the batch request itself is in a special format described in the link above.